# why wilcox.test get different p value when I transform data?

Tags: r

Since both Wilcoxon signed rank test and Wilcoxon rank sum test should be ranked based test. In that case, if I apply monotone function on both variables, the result should be same. But when I use signed rank test by using wilcox.test in R, I get different p values.

```
set.seed(123)
x=rlnorm(100)
y=rlnorm(100)
wilcox.test(x,y,paired = T)
wilcox.test(log(x),log(y),paired = T)
wilcox.test(x,y,paired = F)
wilcox.test(log(x),log(y),paired = F)
```

Comment: I think if you plot(x,y) and then plot(log(x),log(y)) it will be clear.  I don't think that log is a monotonic transformation for all values.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with the Wilcoxon signed rank, but it gives consistent results if you subtract 1 to both vectors instead of taking the log. That is: `wilcox.test(x-1,y-1,paired = T)` gives the same p-value as `wilcox.test(x,y,paired = T)`. I don't think this is an `R` problem, it's likely a stats issue with how the tests transform the data and how the p-values are calculated.

Comment: works for _linear_ transformations, eg, `identical(wilcox.test(x,y,paired = T)$p, wilcox.test(-x[57] * x + x[4] * 45, -x[57] * y + x[4] * 45,paired = T)$p)`